# How can I make a multi client server with more function?

Tags: c, multithreading, tcp, pthreads

I am new in TCP server client program . I want to develop a application in C to authenticate client and receive data from server . I know I need to use thread to handle multiple client . But I am concern about how can I call each functions in server side via thread or any need of creating more threads in server (like worker thread to do each functions) . I have a server which has lot of function like fun1() ,fun2(),fun3(),fun4() to handle the client data .So Is it any problem or delay when I use thread ? because when multiple client come at one sec , how the server handle this case ? I develop a logic like

```
server fun
{
 //thread function calling fun1()
}

void *fun1(void *arg)
{
  fun2()
  pthread_exit((void*)xx)
} 
fun2()
{
  fun3()
}

fun3()
{
}
```

Comment: Thread are not mandatory, you can use ` epoll`  you have an example here https://banu.com/blog/2/how-to-use-epoll-a-complete-example-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

When you are using C you have to use the function accept for incoming connections. accept is a blocking function, so it waits until a connection is established. The return parameter of this function is a socket.

So your next statement after accept should be a creation of a thread with the input parameter of the socket. In your thread you can call your functions fun1,fun2,...

Of course there is a little delay but it's only milliseconds. When multiple clients are going to connect, they are queued.

The advantage of a parallel Server instead of a serial server is that one client can't block your service.